# Hadoop HiveServer2 worker threads - how to get info about them

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

Was getting
HiveServer2 Process - Thrift server getting "Connection refused"

hiveserver2.log flooded with messages similar to

```
2016-01-06 12:19:57,617 WARN [Thread-8]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:serve(184)) - Task has been rejected by ExecutorService 9 times till timedout, reason: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess@753dd4d2 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4408d67c[Running, pool size = 500, active threads = 500, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 12772]
```

being those active 500 the max default hive.server2.thrift.http.max.worker.threads

This was sorted by restarting HS2 but how can I gather more info about
 which YARN job a worker thread maps to
or for how long it has been running ?

Comment: For personal experience I would say that HS2 is a very unstable piece of shoftware. We restart the damn thing every night to minimize the chance of OOM crash at day time... Which version do you run, by the way? And with binary or http protocol?

Comment: Thanks Samson.
So no command/way for us to map those into a process or in any way get more info about them?
Cheers

Comment: You could telnet the port to check for active state and details. As Samson said , hive server 2 isnt stable and we keep on restarting it.